# Ignore DIV if it has a certain class

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function that finds all the DIVS with a class of `boxes`. It then removes the class of `visible`.

I now want to make my function ignore any DIV if it has a class of `important`.

So basically if my DIV only has the classes of `boxes` and `visible`, `visible` will be removed. But if my DIV has the classes of `boxes`, `visible` and `important`, this DIV will be left alone and `visible` will not be removed.

```
$(this).find('.boxes').removeClass('visible');
```

I know this can be done in an `if` statement, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:not(anotherSelector)`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in the selector:

```
$(this).find('.boxes:not(.important)').removeClass('visible');
```

Another way would be using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$(this).find('.boxes').not('.important').removeClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the :not() selector:

```
$(this).find('.boxes:not(.important)').removeClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).find('div.boxes:not(.important)').removeClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('.boxes:not(.important)').removeClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:not()` pseudo-selector:

```
$(this).find(".boxes.visible:not(.important)").removeClass("visible");
```